# SEO friendly URL not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a URL (Example.com/blog/) and `blog` is a directory in my website root. `blog` contains an index.php file that generates a page based on the query string of `?url=[some url]` for example let's say example.com/blog/?url='hello-world' is a valid query string where information can be generated. I want that URL to be example.com/blog/hello-world

Currently, I have a global .htaccess file that removes all extensions. Inside my blog directory is another .htaccess file. It has my attempt at making the URL change to the friendly URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(blog)/(.*)$ blog/index.php?url=$2
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working. How can I solve this problem so the friendly URL displays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/?url=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: For some reason I got a 500 internal server error with this

Comment: Please try now! actually there is $1 instead of $2 because we have only one matching group.

Comment: I modified your code to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/?url=$1 [QSA,NC,L]` and it works now! Thanks a lot.